# How to find a nth primitive root of unity over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For instance, one can find 15th roots of unity by letting $f(x) := x^{15}-1 = (x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1)(x^4 + x + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$. Then roots of $f(x)$ are roots of its factors. e.g. When $\omega$ is a root of $(x^2 + x + 1)$, it is a root of $f(x)$. But how would one go further around with finding a "primitive" root?

Comment: Those primitive roots reside in an extension field (in this case if $GF(16)$ also known as $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ that can be constructed as $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, where $p(x)$ is any irreducible quartic. Back to you factorization. The primitive fifteenth roots of unity are zeros of those factors that are not themselves factors of $x^d-1$ for some proper factor $d\mid 15$. Here $x+1$ is a factor of $x^1-1$, $x^2+x+1$ a factor of $x^3-1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ a factor of $x^5-1$. You need to throw those out

Comment: (cont'd) Because the above list accounts for **all** the factors of $x^3-1$ and $x^5-1$, you are done. The zeros of the remaining two quartic factors are of order fifteen.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Why didn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: So, though it does not sound sophisticated, for small n one would factor $x^n$ and observe factorization of $x^k - 1$ for $k < n$. Then check if factors of $x^n$ would not be found among factors of $x^k$. It's fair enough for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

## First Approach

The roots of unity live on a unit circle and are equally spaced. If you let

$$ x = exp \left(i\theta\right)$$

Then you are greatly simplifying the problem, as you are only considering solutions on the unit circle. As a result:

$$ \exp \left(in\theta\right) - 1 = \exp \left(in\theta\right) - \exp\left( {2\pi ik} \right) $$

Now they are only roots when $\theta = {2 \pi k \over n}$. Which indicates that the roots are spread evenly around the unit circle.

> Note $\exp\left(2\pi i k \right) = \cos(2\pi k) + i \sin(2\pi k) = 1$ always equals 1, since sin is zero for all multiples of $2\pi$.

Hope that helps.

## Alternative Approach

Since $f(x) = x^{15} -1$, it is easy to show that $f(\bar x ) = f(x)$. This means that all roots must occur in conjugate pairs. As a result, the roots of unity must occur in pairs. If you expand these pairs, you always get quadratic terms.

### n is odd

If n is odd, then we must have a factorisation:

$$x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x-\alpha_1)(x-\bar\alpha_1)...$$

### n is even

If n is even, then we have two known roots:

$$x^n - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)(x-\alpha_1)(x-\bar\alpha_1)...$$

Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: The OP is over $\textbf F_2$